# Using If to select dataframe by name from list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

In R: I have a list of 3 dataframes (Book1, Book2, Book3), list named dflist4. I have a code I want to apply to each dataframe separately in the list because the value of maxm is different for each dataframe. I wrote it, and it works, but only when Book1, Book2, and Book3 are all equally sized dataframes. When they are not equally sized, the code will not run (error: ops.dataframe == only defined for equally-sized dataframes). When I change the == to = , i get that it is not logical. Can anyone please give a suggestion as to how to select the dataframes from the list based on their names no matter the size of the dataframe?

Code here:

```
eggplant<-function(x){
(if((x == (dflist4[["Book1"]])){
maxm = 3;
x %>% mutate(Col4 = (x[,3])/maxm);
})
(if((x == dflist4[["Book2"]])){
maxm = 2;
x %>% mutate(Col4 = (x[,3])/maxm);
})
(if((x == dflist4[["Book3"]])){
maxm = 1;
x %>% mutate(Col4 = (x[,3])/maxm);
})
}

test<-lapply(dflist4, eggplant)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data (either post a minimal representative piece of your actual data, or the code to produce representative sample data). This sounds like a quick job for `Map`/`mapply` or `purrr::map2`.

Comment: You are also mixing `dplyr` with base R syntax: Within `mutate` you should refer to columns by name (like `Col4`) not by index (like `x[, 3]`).

Comment: Thanks! Yes col3 is the 3rd column. I am reading your answer now. Why can't you use R base syntax within dplyr? It works... But just isn't correct?

Comment: Take e.g. `x %>% mutate(Col4 = (x[,3])/maxm)`: Don't use `x` inside `mutate`; the whole point of piping and the `dplyr` syntax is to successively apply transformations to your original data `x` which you call once. If you must you could do `x %>% mutate(Col4 = (.[[3]])/maxm)` but this is ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up from my comments above, I assume the third column in `Book1`, `Book2`, `Book3` is called `Col3`.

You can use `purrr::map2`

```
library(tidyverse)
purrr::map2(dflist4, c(3, 2, 1), function(df, maxm) df %>% mutate(Col4 = Col3 / maxm))
```

---

As you don't provide sample data, here is an `mtcars`-based example

```
purrr::map2(list(mtcars[1:3, ], mtcars[1:3, ]), c(10, 100), function(df, maxm)
    df %>% mutate(mpg.new = mpg / maxm))
#[[1]]
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg.new
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    2.10
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    2.10
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    2.28
#
#[[2]]
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg.new
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4   0.210
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4   0.210
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1   0.228
```

Comment: Thank you! I assume that c(3,2,1) would automatically go through assigning 3 to the first dataframe in list, 2 to second, correct?

Comment: What if the data frames switch order? This would force it to be only the order they are in the list and you would have to rewrite c() each time depending on the order you would want it applied, no? Thank you very much by the way for the solution

Comment: @MGru Yes, the whole concept behind `map2`/`mapply`/`Map` is to apply a function to the first elements of each `list` argument, then the second element, then the third, and so on. So the order of elements in the two `list`s needs to match.